# Understanding the camera, getting it to fit 480x800

Tags: unity-game-engine

It might be weird locking on a 480x800 resolution, but I'm having problems understanding the camera in Unity.

I'm trying to build a 2d application with unity 4.3.4, which supports 2d. What I've done Is that I've created a background that is 480x800, but whats confusing is that I cant seem to fit the camera.

If I edit the Size, W and H of the camera, I can get it to fit 480x800 with the values Size=4, W=0.33, H=1. But I think this is really bad approach of the problem.

So how could I do it? I want support a mobile screen size in portrait mode, and with width being atleast 480. The new Samsung galaxy has a 1080 pixels in screenwidth. The ration between screen height and width seems to be 0.5 to 0.6, setting W to be 0.7 and H to be 1 should enable some flexibility?

And when developing for multiple resolutions, what do I do with the background? a 480x800 as I already created would not fit the bill on a 1920x1080 device!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter how you approach this, you'll either:
a) Need a seperate background for each aspect ratio
b) Have parts of your background not be visible when using certain aspect ratios.

There isn't an optimal solution as far as I can see for this sort of problem. The way I approach it is to usually create a background which is wide enough to accommodate the widest possible screen (16:9 logically). The extra background for wide screens is simply ignored on the other aspect ratios. This has the benefit of being quite easy to implement, but depending on your use of the background it may not work for your case.

You could alternatively simply resize the camera, forcing it into the aspect ratio you want (similarly to how you went about it) by calling `Camera.aspect = 4f/3f;` where 4/3 is the aspect ratio you want. This of course is far from pretty, and will distort the final game, depending on the device you're using.

Finally, the easiest solution by far is to simply set the unity background color to Black, and let it fill in any excess with black strips.

Comment: So, in order to obtain 16:9 for instance, I set the camera to size=5, Near=0.3, Far=1000, X=0, Y=0, W=16, H=9 ? Im unsure what the Size does

Comment: to force the camera aspect ratio to 16:9, all you'd need to do is: `Camera.aspect = 16f/9f;`, but as I said, this will end up looking distorted on devices that don't have a 16:9 screen

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I still have a little problem understanding it. As you pointed our it is silly to lock the aspect ratio, but I'm having problems getting my camera to fit 480x800 background. The W should be 0.6 and H=1, but W=0.44 when Size=4 is correct if I want to fit the camera... why is this? With 480x800, W is 0.6 of the height?? Unity is pretty new to me, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the camera, when making a game to be played in portrait mode.

Comment: The Size property change the overall size of the camera, so it change both width and height. Generally you don't really want to be altering this. Width and Height are determined by the device you're using. Height will usually remain the same, but the width changes depending on the size of the screen of the device the game is running on. As I said, your best bet is to change the background depending on the screen size of the device the game is running on.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Steven Mills,  that the best solution is to make all of your artwork to fit within certain range from left to right and make it very  tall something like 16:9.
And than you need to place your assets and you need to use Anchors so  assets are positioned at certain units from left,right,top bottom on the screen.This with the anchors is accomplished differently depending on how you are making the game, are you using the new Texture2D and sprite features or are you using tk2d or something similar.

There are couple usefull links about how to use the property size on a camera to make objects pixel perfect (if you are using the bild in unity classes for 2d):

http://indiehoodgames.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/pixel-perfect-calculator-for-orthographic-camera-unity3d/

http://www.benbarefield.com/blog/2013/01/28/orthographic-camera-in-unity/

The idea behind it is that Unity3d uses meters and you define what is the pixels to meters for each asset and than you define the camera size, how many meters to be rendered always vertically if it is landscape or horizontally if it is portrait mode.